# What is the correct syntax for the Queries parameter in the Logic Apps Function connector?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have an azure function that calculates additional output if you include a query parameter in it's url. I would like to use this function in a logic app, but I am getting an error trying to use the *Queries* parameter of the azure function connector to set the query parameter.

[image: Unable to process template language expressions in action 'JoinJsonArrays' inputs at line '1' and column '1997': 'Error converting value "calculateMergeHint=true" to type 'Microsoft.Azure.Flow.Data.Operations.QueryStringDictionary'. Path 'queries'.']

The Queries parameter is defined as follows:

[image: calculateMergeHint=true]

Comment: Did you run into any issues with your Logic App no longer being able to connect to your Azure Function in the Designer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that the correct syntax is a JSON object.

[image: {"calculateMergeHint": "true"}]